# Optimizing memory usage when running r.viewshed in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, viewshed, memory, grass.script, pygrass

**Short explanation:**
I am using [r.viewshed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.viewshed.html) as part of a script. The viewshed analysis is the most costly (time) part of the script and I'm trying to optimize how quickly it runs (I need to run the viewshed 1000s of times for the analysis). r.viewshed allows you to set the amount of memory to use, however no matter how much memory I allocate in the parameters, I never see a discernable impact on how long the analysis takes nor do I see an impact on my computer's memory usage. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

**More details:**
I have developed the script on my personal PC (windows) running it using the GRASS GUI using the "Launch user-defined script" function. The ultimate goal is to run it from command line on a high-performance computer that I have access to. My PC has 56 GB of memory installed and according to the task manager I generally have between 43 and 46 GB available with normal background programs running. I have tried various memory parameters (most recently 25000 mb and 50000 mb) and it seems to run the same either way. If I watch the performance on my PC, the CPU usage goes up (1% --> ~10%) but the impact on the memory is negligible (9.8 GB --> 10.3 GB). I also looked at the Details section in task manager and it shows r.viewshed using 33756 K while running. I've seen the same thing during the small tests I've done on the high-performance computer (through the Grass GUI).

I'm using a smaller DEM as a test area right now which has 6777870 cells. The actual viewshed analysis is run with a maximum distance of 3400 m. The challenge is that I need to run the viewshed analysis using the centroid of each raster cell as the observer location. I've currently been working with a set of ~12,000 test points, which takes ~7-8 hours to run. My actual study area is much, much larger.

I've included my script here as well if it's helpful.

```
import grass.script as gscript


def main ():
  gscript.run_command('g.region', raster='test_dem1', flags='p')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
from grass.pygrass.vector import Vector
import os
os.environ['GRASS_OVERWRITE'] = '1'

elevation = 'test_dem1'
input_points = 'Test_pts'
output_points = 'Test_output'

tmp_viewshed_name = 'tmp_viewshed'
tmp_visible_points = 'tmp_points'
tmp_point = 'tmp_current_point'

columns = [('cat', 'INTEGER'),
            ('area', 'DOUBLE PRECISION')]

with Vector(input_points, mode='r') as points, Vector(output_points, mode='w', tab_cols=columns) as output:

    for point in points:
        viewshed_id = str(point.cat)
        viewshed_name = 'viewshed_' + viewshed_id
        gscript.run_command('r.viewshed', input=elevation, observer_elevation=1.471, max_distance=3400, output=tmp_viewshed_name, memory=50000, coordinates=point.coords(), flags='crb')
        gscript.mapcalc(exp="{viewshed} = if({tmp}, {vid}, null())".format(viewshed=viewshed_name, tmp=tmp_viewshed_name, vid=viewshed_id))
        cells = gscript.parse_command('r.univar', map=viewshed_name, flags='g')['n']
        area = float(cells) * gscript.region()['nsres'] * gscript.region()['nsres']

        output.write(point, (area, ))
        output.table.conn.commit()

        gscript.run_command('g.remove', type='raster', name=viewshed_name, flags='f')

gscript.run_command('v.to.rast', input='Test_output', type='point', output='Test_vis', use='attr', attribute_column='area')
```

Comment: Maybe I overlook it but please add some information on the DEM size (amount of pixels) which is quite relevant. With small maps the memory consumption will remain small as GRASS GIS is pretty memory efficient.

Comment: @markusN. I'm using a smaller DEM as a test area right now which has 6777870 cells. The actual viewshed analysis is run with a maximum distance of 3400 m.

Comment: Sorry--accidentally posted that before I was finished. The challenge is that I need to run the viewshed analysis using the centroid of each raster cell as the observer location. I've currently been working with a set of ~12,000 test points, which takes ~7-8 hours to run. My actual study area is much, much larger. 

Your comment suggests that I may be focused on the wrong thing in terms of the time needed for the analysis.